Solving systems of equations over arbitrary algebraically closed field
When considering a system of equations over an arbitrary algebraically closed field, does the number of solutions depend on the field? (As long as the equations do not "degenerate"?)
(The following is Exercise 5.2 in Hartshornes Algebraic Geometry. The way the exercise is formulated suggests that the answer to this question is independent of the choice of $k$).
For example, consider the surface given by $xy+x^3+y^3=0$ in $\mathbb{A}^3=k^3$ for any arbitrary algebraically closed field $k$. The exericse is to find all singular points over $k$. First, we compute the Jacobian
$$(y+3x^2, x+3y^2,0)$$
Clearly, $z$ is a free variable. Now for example over the field $\mathbb{R}$ (which is obviously not algebraically closed), the Jacobian vanishes for $(0,0,z)$ and $(-1/3,-1/3,z)$, easily seen from the equation $-3x^2=\sqrt{-x/3}$, respectively $9x^4+x/3=0$. The analog equation exists for $y$. However, only $(0,0,z)$ lies on the surface, thus is the only kind of singularity. Further, over the algebraically closed field $\mathbb{C}$, I can compute all four kinds of solutions ($9x^4+x/3=0$ has four solutions, $z$ is again free), but again only $(0,0,z)$ lies on the curve.
I know that over any such field, there are always at most four solutions.  However, over different fields there could be different solutions, and I have no idea how to argue that over any arbitrary algebraically closed field, there are no solutions that also lie on the surface. That is:
Does the system of all three equations has additional solutions when solving over other algebraically closed fields? Does the answer to this exercise depend on the field $k$?
I know that for the same base field, algebraic closures are isomorphic, but what happens for example over the field $\overline{\mathbb{F}_5}$? Obviously it is not possible to consider every possible field manually, but there should probably be an abstract argument.
Assuming that the number of solutions is independent of the choice of the field, and as $(0,0,z)$ is obviously always a solution, I could deduce that there are no other singular points. However, I think that there should be at least any constraint in the sense that the system of equations should not "degenerate":
For example, consider the simple system $(2x+2,xy)$ which has the only solution $(1,0)$ over the algebraically closed field $\mathbb{C}$, but has infinitely many solutions $(x,0), (0,y)$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$.
I would appreciate any help on this problem!

There is an argument based on the compactness theorem for first order logic and the completeness of the theory of algebraically closed fields. However, it is not as general as you imagine – there can be "small exceptions".

To answer your topline question: yes, the number of solutions will depend on the field $k$, even if $k$ is algebraically closed. Here is a simple example: $x^p=1$ has $p$ distinct roots when $k$ is of characteristic $\neq p$ and only one root when $k$ is of characteristic $p$. This, or the case you've identified above where some coefficient vanishes upon reduction by $p$ leading to "degeneration", are basically the only ways this happens.
Getting more in to the details of your specific example, there are things we can do to check what's going on here, manually, without resorting to an abstract argument. The basic idea is that if we simplify carefully enough, we can make it clear where the potential problems are. The carefullest way to simplify is over $\Bbb Z$, so let's look at whether we can simplify $I=(xy+x^3+y^3,x+3y^2,y+3x^2)\subset\Bbb Z[x,y,z]$ (we're doing this over $\Bbb Z$ so that we know our operations will carry through no matter where we go in the future). Since $y+3x^2$ is in $I$, we have $x(-3x^2)+x^3+(-3x^2)^3=-2x^3-27x^6$ and $x+3(-3x^2)^2=x+27x^4$ in our ideal, hence $-2x^3-27x^6+x^2(x+27x^4)=-x^3$ in our ideal, hence $x+27x^4+27x(-x^3)=x$ in our ideal $I$. By symmetry, $y\in I$ too, so in fact over the integers, $I=(x,y)$, and the singular locus is exactly the line $(0,0,z)$ over any field. So the answer to this particular portion of this exercise does not depend on the base field, but you'll see that there are places where this matters later - the cusp $x^3=y^2+x^4+y^4$ of exercise I.5.6 is sensitive to characteristic 7 and 13, for instance.

In addition to the argument via first order logic that Zhen Lin mentions in the comments, there is a scheme-theoretic way to see that there are only finitely many characteristics where things can go wrong (i.e. you get a different number of solutions than you expected), but I'll leave that one out for now since you're still in chapter I of Hartshorne.

Thank you very much for this answer!
